# How to add color to ionic-selectable items

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm using `ionic-selectable` in my project, and I want to change the color of items.

I put the folowing css as mentions in the doc :

```
.ionic-selectable-item-is-selected,.ionic-selectable-item-is-disabled
 {
   color:red !important;
 }
```

but nothing happend, here's a picture of the result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54ocx.png)

How can I add color to the items please?

Comment: Your css works fine for me, checkout this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-selectable-basic-ivcrdf?file=app/app.component.scss).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I dont know why it doesnt work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

Here your code work well... But you can try more specific code like that.

```
.ionic-selectable-item-is-selected,.ionic-selectable-item-is-disabled
 {
   .label {
    color:red;
   }
 }
```